# MySQL hot backups on database inside a Virtuozzo container

Tags: mysql, backup, virtualization, cdp, r1soft

R1soft's CDP doesn't currently work on MySQL databases inside a Virtuozzo container.

Is there any backup software that offers the same kind of 'continuous data protection'?

An alternative to this would be a host that provided just MySQL hosting with CDP installed, if anyone knows of such a service this would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a modified kernel to perform such kind of things as "volume snapshotting" and it's not possible to modify the kernel when you are in a container. Although it is still possible to perform a hot backup of the MySQL DB if all your tables use InnoDB storage, check Percona's `xtrabackup` tool, it's exactly for that.

Comment: Ok, unfortunately some of the tables are MyISAM...

Comment: If you don't use native MySQL full text search you can convert them to InnoDB easily (and I strongly recommend to do it because MyISAM storage is just not crash safe). Please note  that conversion process locks tables so they are effectively offline during conversion phase so it's better to perform the conversion as soon as possible while you don't have much data.

Comment: Use innobackupex - it will use xtrabackup for innodb and cp (or rsync if you specify option) for myisam